# Use iframe to embed the actual webpage of a YouTube video on moble devices?

Tags: iframe, youtube, youtube-api, mobile-devices

I'm trying to use iframe to embed the **actual webpage** of a YouTube video on my website so that my visitors can login to YouTube, like the video, read the description of the video, browse the comments, leave a comment, subscribe to the channel, ... etc, just like they are on the YouTube website, without leaving my website.

I had tested this code:

```
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=[Video ID]"></iframe>
```

It works for desktop browsers, but not for mobile devices. Mobile devices simply do not load the iframe.

Is it doable?

Comment: Could you provide the logs?

Comment: @abielita Excuse me, what logs?